# ModelForm widget assignment not working in meta class

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to set a widget for a field in a ModelForm. I'd like to set it in the `class Meta` section with the other overrides but this doesn't seem to work:

```
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ['name',]
    widget = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': u'form-control'})
    }
```

Only this works:

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                             'class': u'form-control'}))
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ['name',]
```

Other overrides, like labels, error_messages etc. all work when specificed in the Meta class.

How should I define a wdiget in the Meta class to get it working as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot an 's' (its widgets not widget), also you don't need forms.Widget, just Widget.

```
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ('name',)
    widgets = {
        'name': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': u'form-control'})
    }
```

Comment: Say it isn't so. Damn. Good call!

Comment: if i'm overriding an existing ModelForm, like UserCreationForm, I find that I still need to set everything above the Meta class to effect the override

Comment: You are overriding which means that fields Declared in the original Form are not affected by Meta:
`Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels, help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields that are generated automatically.`

Comment: In order to override them you have to define them above the Meta and configure attributes there.